# How to check and request read, write permission for sd card in platform >= 23 of Android

Tags: android, android-sdcard

I have the following code to request read,write permission for external(shared) storage known as emulated. Now I also want to read and write to SD Card. But i am getting the error "permission denied" in logs.

```
//We are calling this method to check the read permission status
public boolean isReadWriteStorageAllowed() {
    //Getting the permission status
    int resultRead   = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
    int resultWrite  = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);

    //If permission is granted returning true
    if (resultRead == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && resultWrite == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
        return true;

    //If permission is not granted returning false
    return false;
}

public void requestStoragePermission(int code){

    if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)) {
    }
    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, code);
}
```

> The logs for the error are as below

```
    10-12 14:23:03.998 8550-8550/com.free W/System.err: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/8E14-3919/database.db (Permission denied)
10-12 14:23:03.998 8550-8550/com.free W/System.err:     at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(Native Method)
10-12 14:23:03.998 8550-8550/com.free W/System.err:     at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:221)
10-12 14:23:03.998 8550-8550/com. free W/System.err:     at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:108)
10-12 14:23:03.998 8550-8550/com.free W/System.err:     at com. DatabaseManage.exportDatabase(DatabaseManage.java:140)
10-12 14:23:03.998 8550-8550/com.free W/System.err:     at com. DatabaseManage.access$000(DatabaseManage.java:50)
10-12 14:23:03.998 8550-8550/com.free W/System.err:     at com. DatabaseManage$1.onClick(DatabaseManage.java:106)
10-12 14:23:03.999 8550-8550/com.free W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.app.AlertController$AlertParams$3.onItemClick(AlertController.java:1244)
10-12 14:23:03.999 8550-8550/com.free W/System.err:     at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:339)
10-12 14:23:03.999 8550-8550/com.free W/System.err:     at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1695)
10-12 14:23:03.999 8550-8550/com.free W/System.err:     at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:4171)
10-12 14:23:03.999 8550-8550/com.free W/System.err:     at android.widget.AbsListView$13.run(AbsListView.java:6772)
10-12 14:23:03.999 8550-8550/com.free W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
10-12 14:23:03.999 8550-8550/com.free W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
10-12 14:23:03.999 8550-8550/com.free W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
10-12 14:23:03.999 8550-8550/com.free W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6692)
10-12 14:23:03.999 8550-8550/com.free W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
10-12 14:23:03.999 8550-8550/com.free W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1468)
10-12 14:23:03.999 8550-8550/com.free W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1358)
```

My question is 'if asking the storage permissions for external storage' will also grant the permissions for 'sd card'? If not then whats wrong in my code or what am i missing? I need a solution!

> The code is as under

```
public void exportDB(){
    int size, pathSize = 0;
    String[] storageLocations = null;

    final File dbFile = context.getDatabasePath(DATABASE_NAME);//existing database file path

    File device = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();//device storage
    String[] sdCard = getExternalStorageDirectories();//sd cards

    size = sdCard.length;

    if(size == 0)
        pathSize = 0;
    else if(size > 0)
        pathSize = size + 1;

    pathForExports   = new String[pathSize];
    storageLocations = new String[pathSize];

    if(sdCard.length == 0){
        pathForExports[0]   = device.getAbsolutePath() + "/" + DATABASE_NAME;
        storageLocations[0] = "1) Device Storage";
    }
    else if(sdCard.length > 0) {
        pathForExports[0] = device.getAbsolutePath() + "/" + DATABASE_NAME;
        storageLocations[0] = "1) Device Storage";

        for (int i=0;i<sdCard.length; i++) {
            File file = new File(sdCard[i]);
            pathForExports[i+1] = file.getAbsolutePath() + "/" + DATABASE_NAME;
            if(sdCard.length > 1) {
                storageLocations[i+1] = (i+2) + ") Sd Card - " + (i+1);
            }
            else
                storageLocations[i+1] = (i+2) + ") Sd Card";
        }
    }
    //File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator + SAMPLE_DB_NAME);

    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
    builder.setTitle("Choose Export Location");
    builder.setItems(pathForExports, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            exportDatabase(dbFile, which);
        }
    });
    AlertDialog alertDialog = builder.create();
    alertDialog.show();
}

private void exportDatabase(File dbFile, int whichButton) {

    FileChannel source = null;
    FileChannel destination = null;

    try {
        source = new FileInputStream(dbFile).getChannel();
        destination = new FileOutputStream(pathForExports[whichButton]).getChannel();
        destination.transferFrom(source, 0, source.size());
        source.close();
        destination.close();

        if(whichButton == 0)
            alert("Database is exported to device storage");
        else
            alert("Database is exported to sd Card");
    } catch(IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        if(whichButton == 0)
            alert("Failed to export database to device storage");
        else
            alert("Failed to export database to sd card");
    }
}
```

Comment: `for external(shared) storage known as emulated. ` ???? What do you mean? Never saw such.

Comment: so you mean to say: sd card/android//data/com.free/database.db

Comment: by external(shared) i mean the device storage not sd card!

Comment: why the negative votes ???

Comment: I think because you did not post the code that produces that exception. And although you speak about sd card in the subject of your post you later deny that it is about sd card.

Comment: one more query; if it is not possible to write to sd card than is it possible to read from it? take the example of audio players. They read from sd cards in order to play the songs or the videos?

Comment: Mostly it is possible. Yes. Mostly.

Answer (score 1):

```
    /storage/8E14-3919/database.db .
```

Even if you have all the permissions for external storage then still you will not be able to write on the micro SD card on that place.

You can only write in the app specific directory on the card.

To find that path use getExternalFilesDirs(). If you are lucky it is one of the entries returned.

For you the path would look like

```
 /storage/8E14-3919/Android/data/<packagename>/files
```

Have a look with a file explorer app. It is probably already there.

If you want to write everywhere on the card use the storage access framework.

Comment: by external(shared) i mean the devicez storage not the sd card. So you mean to say that i cannot read to: sd card/database.db but instead to sd card/android/data/com.free/database.db ..... is that what you meant to say ..

Comment: i have seen a lot of apps backing there data to the sd cards? i am not sure about your statement!!

Comment: /storage/8E14-3919 IS the sd card! So where are you talking about?

Comment: can you give an idea or code about storage access fremework??

Comment: So what do you mean.. The device storage or the sd card? You should be clear first.

Comment: it is the storage we get with File device = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();//device storage

Comment: That will not give you  /storage/8E14-3919. And where is the emulated? If it does i would like to know which device does.

Comment: i have separate code to get sd card .... the above piece of code is definitely getting /storage/emulated/0

Comment: Yes indeed that wiil give /storage/emulated/0. But the exception is for  /storage/8E14-3919 so how did you get that? And where are you talking about?

Comment: ??? You should tell how you come to  /storage/8E14-3919 instead. And you should make us clear if you mean the sd card yes or no. Your post is confusing. But what does it matter.. You are clearly trying to write on the sd card. And that is impossible as i stated in my answer.

Comment: you want me to post the coode?

Comment: No. It does not matter anymore. We are finished. You have the answer on `what am i missing?`.